# Shall "Require.js" await upon response?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two code samples, they don't contain the complete project only the problem I'm facing.

I'm using "Require.js" with "Three.js".

socket.js:

```
define(["three", "varibles", "socketio"], function(THREE, varibles, io) {
        var candlesData;
        var socket = io.connect(varibles.scoket_dest);
        console.log('In socket!');
        socket.on('candles', function(data) {
                candlesData = JSON.parse(data.jsoncandles);
                if (Array.isArray(candlesData)) {
                        console.log('Yes, Array!');
                        console.log('In, Array!');
                        console.log(candlesData);
                }
        });
        return candlesData;
});
```

app.js:

```
define(["three", "camera", "controls", "geometry", "light", "material", "renderer", "scene", "socket"],
  function(THREE, camera, controls, geometry, light, material, renderer, scene, socket) {
    var app = {
      meshes: [],
      init: function() {
        window.addEventListener('change', renderer);

        if (socket) {
          console.log('Socket exist!');
          console.log(socket);
        } else {
          console.log('Socket dosnt exist!');
          console.log(socket);
        }

        console.log('In app!');

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.cube, material.candleShortBodyMat);
        light.target = mesh;
        scene.add(mesh);
      },
      animate: function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(app.animate);
        controls.update();
        // Rotate all meshes we've added to scene
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
    };
    return app;
});
```

Within "app.js" is what's related to the question.

```
if (socket) {
    console.log('Socket exist!');
    console.log(socket);
} else {
    console.log('Socket dosnt exist!');
    console.log(socket);
}

console.log('In app!');
```

Response sent by the program.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw5Ty.png

**What I'd like to see happening:** Canvas loads, in the meantime the Socket I/O connects and as soon as the reply arrives I'd like to work with it.

**What happens currently:** Canvas loads-in, and the Socket returns the reply already, which is nothing, since it didn't have time to even connect. And then the Socket loads in the data. But I cannot do anything with it.

How would it be possible to achieve that the Canvas shall load, but as soon as there's any data coming from the Socket I/O, it shall display it in the console.log?
Display shall occur to "app.js".

Comment: It looks as though you have a race condition. In your socket.js module you are only returning the value of candlesData. This data is only populated when your event "candles" is executed. So when your require statement asks for socket.js, it is loading the module, but the "candles" event may not be fired prior to hitting your init function in app.js, thus resulting in returning an undefined "candlesData" variable. I could be way off though, but I would start by investigating what triggers the `socket.on("candles", function(){});` portion of socket.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the application flow doesn't wait for the result of `socket.on('candles')` event, that's why all `console.log()` calls are executed long before the socket returns any data.

Probably the best way to overcome problems with asynchronous execution is to use promises/deferreds. There are several libraries that implement the [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) specification, arguably the most popular is [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Your implementation of **socket.js** would become something like:

```
define(["varibles", "socketio", "q"], function(varibles, io, Q) {
  var deferredCandle = Q.defer();
  var socket = io.connect(varibles.scoket_dest);
  socket.on('candles', function(data) {
    var candlesData = JSON.parse(data.jsoncandles);
    deferredCandle.resolve(candlesData);
  });
  return deferredCandle.promise;
});
```

**app.js**:

```
define([ /* (...) */ "socket"],
  function( /* (...) */ socket) {
    var app = {
      init: function() {
        socket.then(function(candlesData) {
          // this gets executed only when deferredCandle is resolved
          console.log('Socket exist!');
        });
        // (...)
      },
    };
    return app;
  });
```

---

*I was considering flagging this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1240557) but I guess it's a bit different with RequireJS in the mix; either way, there's a lot reading in there if you're interested in the subject.*

Comment: Thank you for this, I haven't heard anything about q yet, but it works now.